# Botkit with HTTPS

Tags: node.js, ssl, slack, slack-api, botkit

I am having trouble getting botkit to run on the https protocol. Here's my setup:

- I have my own VPS running Centos6.
- I am using [botkit-starter-slack](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-slack)
- I have SSL certs that pass [SSLLabs tests](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) via port 443 with apache listening.
- My bot runs on port 3000, per botkit's recommendation, which is a port I have opened.

My bot starts up and runs fine, but it only works through http. If I load a regular webpage with https (apache, 443), it does fine. But I can't get the botkit to respond to https on port 3000. When I reached out to botkit people, they thought the cert might have issues. But the cert passes SSL Labs tests. I copy/pasted Slack support's comments in the screenshot below:

[Here are screenshots of what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMNog.jpg)

Between the cert, slack, and botkit, I'm not sure where my problem is. The support I've received has been nice but...

- If port 3000 is open, why would http work and not https?
- If this is a botkit issue, does anyone know how to tell it to look for https? I've been told essentially, that botkit should JUST WORK on https if https is available.
- Given I'm trying to run this entirely from my VPS, Is there a better suited botkit distribution

Any help would be amazing.

EDIT - I went ahead and did cURL's on everything relevant. Every url worked fine except for, not surprisingly, the https one with port 3000. I got a `(35) SSL Connect` error. At this point, from scouring the web and talking to people, it sounds like my two best options are reverse proxying port 3000 to port 443 or delving into the botkit code line by line to see if there's some crucial step that is causing the issue. I'll give this thread one last bump to see if anyone has any info. Thanks.

Comment: I am not a great sys admin, but I don't think that you can open a secure connection with port 3000 without stepping deeper in your web servers config. Have you tried running the bot on Port 443?